# How to delete all li from the ul when I press the button again

Tags: javascript

I am creating a li through the DOM but if I press the button again without first refresh the page, the elements are added instead of deleting the old ones and adding the new ones, thanks

here are the code:

```
data.cast.forEach((actors)=>{
                const li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = 
                `<li>
                   ${actors.actor}: ${ actors.character} 
                </li>`
                cast.append(li)
            })
```

Comment: To remove the old `<li>` elements empty the `<ul>` node with `cast.innerHTML = ""`

Comment: Can you explain me a little better please, I'm a little new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the old before adding the new:

```js
var cast = document.getElementById('cast');

var data = {
  cast: [{
    actor: "Act01",
    character: "Char01"
  }, {
    actor: "Act02",
    character: "Char02"
  }]
};

document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // delete the list
  cast.innerHTML = '';
  // insert the new
  data.cast.forEach((actors) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `${actors.actor}: ${ actors.character}`;
    cast.append(li);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="cast">
<li>Old actor: Old charactor</li>
</ul>

<button id="replace">Replace with new</button>
```